# Error In Push Notification on Distribution

Tags: ios, iphone

I have implement the push notification after create the ck.pem file on development end. But when i create on distribution end then we check the ck.pem file is correct or not.I have error show below:-

pksinghs-Mac-mini:SchoolPush pksingh$ php /Users/pksingh/Desktop/SchoolPush/simplepush.php

Warning: stream_socket_client(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14094416:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert certificate unknown in /Users/pksingh/Desktop/SchoolPush/simplepush.php on line 21

Warning: stream_socket_client(): Failed to enable crypto in /Users/pksingh/Desktop/SchoolPush/simplepush.php on line 21

Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (Unknown error) in /Users/pksingh/Desktop/SchoolPush/simplepush.php on line 21
Failed to connect: 0 
pksinghs-Mac-mini:SchoolPush pksingh$

i have ck.pem file and pushnofication.php in same folder on desktop.
Can anybody help me.

Answer (score 0):

Find the tutorial for how to create certificate and implement notification from below link

https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial

you can use below command to create certificate

so there are something wrong in creating distribution certificate

**Use below command to create certificate**

openssl x509 -in aps_production.cer -inform der -out PushChatCert.pem

openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out PushChatKey.pem -in Certificates_dist.p12

cat PushChatCert.pem PushChatKey.pem > ck_dist.pem

openssl s_client -connect gateway.push.apple.com:2195 -cert PushChatCert.pem -key PushChatKey.pem

**where**

aps_production.cer = downloaded from developer apple

Certificates_dist.p12 = Exported from your keychain after installing aps_production.cer

Comment: Actually I have implement the push Notification on Development. It works perfect. But now i want to implement on Distribution Side.So i have error.

Comment: Actuall I have save the certificate name as cert.pem and key name as key.p12

Comment: what is the certificate name which you have download from developer.apple?

Comment: ios_distribution.cer

Comment: then just replace aps_production.cer with ios_distribution.cer   and  Certificates_dist.p12 with  key.p12

Comment: And cert.p12 file where use.

Comment: Actually i have use these command:-

openssl pkcs12 -clcerts -nokeys -out cert.pem -in cert.p12
openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out key.pem -in key.p12
openssl rsa -in key.pem -out key.unencrypted.pem
chmod 400 key.unencrypted.pem
cat cert.pem key.unencrypted.pem > ck.pem